# Does $L_2$ convergence imply boundedness?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, measure-theory

Assume that $f_n$ is a sequence of random variables in the space $L^2(\lambda_T \otimes P)$ such that it converges to $f$. $\lambda_T$ is the Lebesgue measure in $[0,T]$.

In this case, how can we show that $E\int_0^T |f_n(s)+f(s)|^2ds$ is uniformly bounded as $L^2(\lambda_T\otimes P)-\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n = f$?

For this I need to essentially show that $E\int_0^T |f_n(s)|^2ds$ is uniformly bounded over $n$. Does this imply that L2 convergence implies uniform boundedness of the sequence? If so, how can we show this?

Comment: Any conveegent sequence in a normed linear space is bounded in the norm.

Comment: @geetha290krm Could you help me see it in this case with both the expectation and the integral?

Comment: The norm in $L^2(\lambda_T \otimes P)$ is, by definition, $\sqrt {E\int_0^{T}|f(s)|^{2}ds} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply triangle inequality and get, $|f_n(s)+f(s)|^2 \leq (|f_n(s)|+|f(s)|)^2  = |f_n(s)|^2 + |f(s)|^2 + 2 |f(s)||f_n(s)|$.

$E\int_0^T |f_n(s)+f(s)|^2 \leq E(\int_0^T |f_n(s)|^2 ds) + E(\int_0^T |f(s)|^2 ds) + 2 E(\int_0^T|f(s)||f_n(s)| ds)$

By Cauchy Schwartz inequality,
$$E\left(\int_0^T|f(s)||f_n(s)| ds \right) \leq \sqrt{E(\int_0^T|f_n(s)|^2 ds)} \times \sqrt{E(\int_0^T|f(s)|^2 ds)}$$

So enough to show that $E(\int_0^T |f_n(s)|^2 ds)$ is bounded uniformly. If the norm in your convergence is $||f_n||^2 = E(\int_0^T |f_n(s)|^2 ds)$ (as @geetha said in comments) then since $||f_n - f|| \rightarrow 0 \implies ||f_n-f|| < \epsilon$ for $n > N_{\epsilon}$. Hence $||f_n|| < ||f||+\epsilon$ for all $n > N_{\epsilon}$. Hence $||f_n||^2$ uniformly bounded by $\max(\max\{||f_n||:n \leq N_{\epsilon}\},||f||+\epsilon)$.